# Which was the first anime to feature a transformable robot?

Tags: anime-history

Even if *Transformers* count as anime (it was made by Americans and Japanese concept: Americans/Japanese, Americans producers, Japanese animation mainly so I guess it's debatable) there were shows with transformable robots before that (ie: *Genesis Climber MOSPEADA*).

Then, which was the first anime to feature transformable robots or at least one transformable robot?

Comment: What is your scope of "transformation"?  If it's unrestricted, one could argue that Astro Boy would be the first anime to feature those.

Comment: I havent seen Astro Boy, in which way does it transform? or what does it transform into?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to specify whether you mean Full body transformation, aka transformer: robot > car. Or partional transformations, such as feet into rockets, or arms into weapons.

Comment: I havent seen partial transformations or I dont remember them. I guess I was thinking in full transformations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Makoto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/102/makoto) already mentions in the comments, depending on what you count as `transformable` the answers might differ a bit.

But with the current scope the first `anime` to feature transformable robots would be Mighty Atom (Astro Boy) in 1963, shortly followed by Tetsujin 28 in the same year.

However, the first Japanese comic to feature this came out in the year 1934  strip was called Tanku Tankuro, which also is the name of the main character.

There is a very interesting topic about it over at the [superherohype forums](http://forums.superherohype.com/showthread.php?t=319060) Which has some more in depth insight on transforming robots in Japan.

Comment: I'm going to accept it, but for reading the link you've posted, the first anime to feature transformable robots to me looks to be Ambassador Magma from 1965. I havent seen Astroboy so I cant comment much, but in that link it says it featured combiners (kinda like Voltron) . Anyway, the answer is about there.

Comment: @Pablo ambassador magma's animation is from 1993. The ambassador magma you are referring to is likely the manga, as this was released in 1965. But if we count manga's/ comics as well, there are, as previously mentioned, even earlier releases ;)

Comment: ohh I see. Then I guess, the one from 1975?

Comment: 1934, Tanku Tankuro, Similar to Transformers, Tanku Tankuro turns himself into a vehicle.